# Terraform: Passing multiple aliases in aws_cloudfront_distribution resource

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass multiple aliases records in `aws_cloudfront_distribution`. I tried to use join to separate strings from the list with a delimiter but its giving below error.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
...
...
...
aliases = [
    "${join(", ", var.aliases)}",
  ]
...
...
}
```

var.aliases is defined in the parent module as below.

```
aliases     = ["a.domain.com", "b.domain.com"]
```

It is trying to replace the current record as below. It is happening because I have added aliases from the GUI console.

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

      ~ module.cms_cloudfront_distribution.aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution
 aliases.#:          "2" => "1"
 aliases.1679894134: "" => "a.domain.com, b.domain.com"
 aliases.2810533754: "a.domain.com" => ""
 aliases.3301490091: "b.domain.com" => ""
```

Comment: Why are you trying to join a list into a string when the aliases part just wants the list? Drop the unnecessary `join` function and you should be fine.

Comment: There was a mistake in the parent module. I was passing the same name for both alias records and it was trying to remove one.

Comment: So you no longer have an issue?

Comment: Yes, It is solved.